# Expose traffic using Ingress Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I am new to Kubernetes. I followed [Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) from Kesley Hightower and also [this](https://github.com/ivanfioravanti/kubernetes-the-hard-way-on-azure) to set up Kubernetes in Azure. Now all the services are up and running fine. But I am not able to expose the traffic using Load balancer. I tried to add a `Service` object of type `LoadBalancer` but the external IP is showing as `<pending>`. I need to add ingress to expose the traffic.

nginx-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-service
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - <ip>
  ports:
    - name: "80"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: "443"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: nginx-service
```

Thank you,

Comment: where is the cluster deployed ? local, on Prem, public cloud?

Comment: Its in cloud (azure)

Comment: What IP are you using on `externalIPs: - <ip>`? Have you tried to use the IP of one of your master nodes? Using Ingress will lead you to the same problem as it also uses the LoadBalancer to get an external IP.

Comment: I have tried with the master node IP. But the same issue, it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the solution proposed by Kubernetes The Hard Way doesn't include a solution for LoadBalancer. The fact it's pending forever is expected behavior. You need to use out-of-the box solution for that. A very commonly used is [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

MetalLB isn't going to allocate an External IP for you, it will allocate a internal IP inside our VPC and you have to create the necessary routing rules to route traffic to this IP.